# Route specific port traffic to specific IP address

Tags: windows, networking, firewall

I have a server (Server A) in internal network and I don't want to place it in DMZ zone. I have another one (Server B) in DMZ and they comm. each other. I won't bother you with their configs.

I need a solution for tcp 443 traffic coming to DMZ zone (from wan) **to redirect it to a specific IP address in LAN network (from DMZ to LAN)**. In short, I need a setup for redirection for TCP 443 from Server B to A.

Guys, can you give me some ideas please? Can this be done with RRAS?

Thanks..

Comment: As long as TCP 443 means "HTTPS" you could just use a reverse proxy (IIS, Apache., nginx).

Answer (score 1):

You're compromising your zoning concept.

The DMZ should be the only zone where external traffic terminates. If you forward external traffic into your LAN zone, you are bypassing the DMZ and potentially expose your entire network. Consider using a VPN tunnel if possible.

*Technically*, it should be no problem to forward port 443 into your LAN, but you haven't told us anything about your network (topology, firewalls, address schemes).